# Data not loading on partial view, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

**I am doing work on form where user can enter a customer record....View is scaffold with Create controller.
On 'Create' View, user can enter 'engineNo' to check its details which passes to another action "CheckRecord",,it can be seen from view...**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="enginNo" />
    <input type="button" value="search" id="btnSearch" />
</form>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="info">
@{Html.RenderAction("CheckRecord","Sales");}
</div>
   some create fields
  }
```

The Create and "CheckRecord" actions are,,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.CustomersDMs, "CustomerId", "Name");
ViewBag.SMClientBranchId = new SelectList(db.SMClientBranchesDMs, "SMClientId", "Name");
  ViewBag.EngineNumber = new SelectList(db.StockDMs, "EngineNumber", "ChasisNumber");
return View();
}

public ActionResult CheckRecord(string enginNo)
{
var results = db.StockDMs.Where(c=>c.EngineNumber ==enginNo);
return PartialView("_part",results);
}
```

And my partialview,,,

```
@model IEnumerable<SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutoCompanyBrand.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SMClientBranch.Name)
        </td>
}
```

**My problem is, the partial view is rendered correctly but the Model of partial view doesn't have value,,,Why is that, i am doing something wrong...Please help,,,Thanks for your time**

Comment: instead of `return PartialView("_part",results);` try `return PartialView("_part",results.ToList());`

Comment: What do you mean _"partial view doesn't have value,"_? You have 2 forms, the first does not even have a control which will post back anything so a little hard to understand what you doing here.

Comment: Thanks for reply, after putting checks on partial view, it seems statement (var item in Model) is terminated after Model

Comment: in simple words, valus are not being passed to PartialView...

Comment: That'll happen if the model is empty. You're not passing any "enginNo" to the action you posted.

Comment: You not passing a value to the parameter `enginNo` so you query is in effect `.Where(c => c.EngineNumber == null);`

Comment: Thanks All for your time,,,,,i understand,,, sorry for my mistake,, i was lately using ajax and then removed...i cost me time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posting this as answer since I mentioned it in comments and that's not the correct place)*

Your action `CheckRecord(string enginNo)` takes an argument of `enginNo`, but you're calling it without any argument. That in turn means your db lookup will most likely not return any results, unless you get results on..

```
var results = db.StockDMs.Where(c => c.EngineNumber == null);
```

Make sure the action gets a valid argument, for example:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("CheckRecord", "Sales", new { enginNo = "abc123" }); }
```